# Are there other places with wind tunnel "wings"?

Tags: where-on-earth, architecture

On a recent visit to Leeds I experienced and learned about the history of the wind tunnel effect from Leeds' tallest building [Bridgewater Place](http://www.bridgewaterplace.co.uk/) and the [remediation](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-leeds-41608461) the council have put in place to minimise its effect to pedestrians.

On a mildly windy day in general the wind tunnel effect was strong in that area and the new "wings" put in place did not seem to have much effect on conditions on the ground.

The design and place of the installed "wings" led me to think if there are any more examples or designs in other places, specifically the UK or Europe? I am not aware of any I have seen on my travels but I must admit I have not been looking.

Answer (score 7):

The structures are referred to as wind baffles, designed to reduce the speed of the wind. Wind resistance or deflection devices are found in both the natural and built environment, such as in [avalance zones](http://www.fao.org/docrep/006/AD075E/AD075e08.htm) and [on and around buildings](https://www.wbdg.org/resources/wind-safety-building-envelope).

Similar to Leeds, the Steel Galleria Trees in downtown Calgary, Alberta, Canada were installed in 2000 (open stock photo):

[image]

And another example, the open-air opera house in Santa Fe, New Mexico, USA (design and image by DRadheshwar Architect):

[image]